# How scipy.dist.rvs() works is unclear from documentation

Tags: python, scipy, time-complexity

I am currently sampling from a custom discrete distribution like so:

```
discrete_dist = stats.rv_discrete(name='discrete_dist', values=(np.arrange(1,N), p))

samples = discrete_dist.rvs(size = m)
```

where *p* is a list of probabilities of length *N*.

I can't figure out, when I look through the documentation what the computational complexity is, as the only thing the documentation says about the rvs() function is the following:

```
def rvs(self, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs['discrete'] = True
    return super().rvs(*args, **kwargs)
```

Link to the documentation [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L3087-L3117). How does the function work?

**Bonus question:** Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The code for discrete distributions with explicit `values` is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L3710

Basically, it's an inverse  distribution function sampling, which transforms a uniform variate on (0, 1) using the inverse of the cdf.